# Convert stacked points into grid

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have a lot of stacked points/coordinates. With the point displacement function inside QGIS I can render these stacked dots into a circle.
[image: stacked dots into circle]

But I like to organize these points into a grid like this example:
[image: stacked dots into grid]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Maybe a modification of https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/PointsDisplacement.py would be required, but it might need to respect some sorting by a third field.

Answer (score 2):

How's your coding skills? It would be a relatively straightforward change in the QGIS code to add this. Basically the block at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/core/symbology-ng/qgspointdisplacementrenderer.cpp#L249 would need an extra option handling grid based positions.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS 3.0 version now offers the "Grid" option for placement method when using point displacement tool.

[image]

You can then use the categorized option to classify your points, like you did with the circular option of the point displacement tool.

Comment: To add to this answer, after categorising your points, you should then use "Layer rendering -> Control feature rendering order" to have the different categories grouped together, as shown in the original question's example.